How to render hyperlinks in the text of a Document in different color without modifying the Document?
I'm trying to highlight links within a Document in blue. I can identify where they are. My problem is I was unable to make them render in blue, without modifying the document. The obvious option would be to apply attributes to the text to straight up color it blue, or just to mark that this part of the text is a link. I can't use this approach, because I don't want to modify the Document for reasons I won't go into.
A ViewFactory lets me create a different View for each element of the document. However, one element can contain some characters which correspond to regular text and some characters which correspond to a link. Two solutions come to mind:

Break up the view into multiple views, one for each link and one for each string of regular text.
I was unable to achieve this without it breaking horribly. If you know how to do this, that would be great.
Change how the view is painted (in the paint method) and paint a portion of the text in blue.
I have no idea how to do this or if it's even doable.

If you know how to achieve solution 1, 2 or some even better solution, I'll be grateful for your help.

"I was unable to make them render in blue, without modifying the document."  Make a copy of the Document and modify the copy.

This is also problematic because the document is supposed to be editable by the user, but thanks for the idea.
